What is the effect of reducing the active and reactive power rate for an inverter?
Many solar inverters which can be controlled remotely have the option to reduce the active and reactive power rate (inductive, capacitive) below 100%. An additional option is the export limit in a percentage. My understanding of the export limit is that this percentage relates to the total capacity of the inverter.
What is the effect of reducing the active and reactive power rate?

Can you explain active and reactive power?

https://control.com/technical-articles/active-power-reactive-power-apparent-power-and-the-role-of-power-factor/

Do you get charged for reactive power on your bill?

No. I am merely interested in the actual effects of changing these parameters.

@SolarMike, my very non-industrial office has a kVAR-Hour (Kilo Volt-Ampere Reactive) meter in the basement.  Do we get charged separately for that? I don't believe so, they just keep an eye on us to make sure we don't go crazy.

@user1683793 homes don't get charged, but many countries do charge businesses as they can get high phase angles. Businesses have correcting units fitted to deal with it and we had to calculate and fit one for a wind turbine. The company we found sold us a very good solution.
